How do I know number of smaller files vs number of bigger files distribution for analytical purpose?
So, I want to perform an analysis to determine the best allocation unit size (cluster size) decision on HDD. As we know, HDD is slow in IOPS but not that slower for IO rate.
The default NTFS cluster size is 4KB. Which means that if I store a file at 1KB, the rest of the 3KB is wasted space. If I set the cluster size to the maximum, which is 2MB, it would be more than wasted space, spending 2MB on just a 1KB file.
On the other side, if I store a 4MB file on a 4KB cluster size, that means there's many IO operations that should be performed. For example, in a read operation, the number of read operations that need to be performed is 4000/4, which is 1000 times read operations (1000 IOPS). Compared to a 2MB cluster size, the number of read operations is just 4000/2000, which is 2 times of read operations (2 IOPS).
Thus, what I mean is that IOPS is not the same as IO rate; IO rate depends on HDD RPM, while IOPS depends on seek time (latency). 
Therefore, I want to find the optimum value of cluster size, not too minimum (4KB) and not too maximum (2MB) based on my file statistics and, in general, most people too.
I want to create a D: drive. It's a general-purpose drive, so it's unknown what type of file it might be, maybe videos (a big file) or maybe many txt files for my notes (small files).
I have an existing C:\Users\User, and now I want to analyse the distribution of file size. The outcome will look like this if it's visualised.

